# Lib for validating the structure of REST response

Tags: python, rest, api, swagger, openapi

I've had a yaml file with OpenAPI 3.0 structure. In my tests i want validate the structure of the REST response against the yaml file. For the Python i've only found the FLEX lib, but it's only works for swagger, not for OpenAPI

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [Schemathesis](https://github.com/schemathesis/schemathesis). It uses property-based testing to generate tests and verify that everything declared in the schema matches the backend implementation. It checks response status code, content-type headers, and response schemas. It supports both Open API 2 and 3.

It is a Python library but has a CLI and could be extended with various hooks to fit the desired workflow.